# Remove double quotes from text inside JSON using Python and Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have millions of JSON objects formated as string with a little text inside. For example:

```
'{"node": {"text": "Você entra numa livraria de livros jurídicos você tem 
uma pilha de livros dizendo: "você pode fazer isso". Ao lado você tem uma 
pilha de livros que contestam exatamente isso. Assim são as discussões 
sobre a legalidade da flexibilização do porte de armas. Eu examinei bem 
profundamente isso porque sou uma defensor da legítima defesa tive mais 
tempo que o próprio presidente para observar item a item e o presidente 
pode ficar tranquilo!"}}'
```

I was able to replace the single quotes as double quotes for the JSON module to accept it. But I am experiencing a lot of errors because of double quotes inside the 'text'. I'm trying to write a regex expression to deal with it. The code i wrote replace not only the first double quote, but the ones just after 'text'.

```
re.sub(r'(:\s+"*)', ' ', text)
```

How could I write a regex that clean both double quotes from "você pode fazer isso" and keep the ones after 'text' intact?

Comment: You say you have millions of JSON objects but that is not valid JSON so are you sure about this?

Comment: You should investigate fixing whatever created these objects in the first place.

Comment: @roganjosh this is just a small part of the entire JSON

Comment: @GuilhermeFelitti and it's invalid as JSON, the string starting `Você entra numa` isn't enclosed in any quotation marks. Is that a transcription error?

Comment: @roganjosh my mistake. the original content have double quotes, but my regex is "cleaning" it. I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: You need to edit the inner quotes to look like: `\\"você pode fazer isso\\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```regex
\"([^{\":]+)\"(?!:)
```

and replace with this:

```regex
$1
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/N0YePo/1)